# Unable to call index.html of Angular 14 from JSP page - Both are running as a Separate App not inside

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jsp

IN my project , I have JSP app and Angular 14 App which are running parallels on same tomcat .
Now , I want to target index.html of Angular from JSP page So whenever JSP page will call it will automatically call index.html inside and load the index.html .
Kindly provide your input if someone has any idea.

[image]

I tired couple of situation .

1. Provide the static file index.html path in main.jsp file . like
   <%@include file = "./project/index.html">
   but it is not working because diffcult to provide index.html path hence both of JSP and Angular project running separately . Yes , Above concept worked once put angular folder inside JSP.
2. Loading like below

   // JavaScript code here
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Load the content dynamically
            $('#contentDiv').load('/project/index.html');
        });

Few lines of HTML code and then

This working first step like hitting index.html but internal route is not working . Yes , I cross checked base url property .
I found in analysis that route does not work in Jquery .

Comment: I use index.jsp as the welcome page for my web app.  In that file I have my  links to the .js files that Angular needs to work and it has the app-root tag that starts Angular.  JSP works on the server and sends the HTML  to the browser.  At the client, the browser loads the JavaScript from the .js files and starts execution at the app-root tag.  Thus JSP   and Angular work together to create web app. JSP works first at server and Angular works second at the client.